# Why do I get error "Unable to resolve dependency" when I try fetch .jar library file from private Nexus repository using gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, repository, nexus, credentials

I want to use the library from private Nexus repository. I added 
the url and credentials to the build.gradle file. But gradle 
project sync fails.

I can download the library via curl "curl -X GET -u user:password 
$URL -O". So I think no problems with the permissions unless there 
is special permission for gradle.

From the same repository, I can use another library via gradle in 
android studio which does not need credentials.

```
//inside project build.gradle file:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username = 'mystringusername'
                password = 'mystringpassword'
            }
            url "mystringurl"
        }
    }
}

//inside app module build.gradle file
dependencies { implementation 'xxx:xxx-retrofit2:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT' }
```

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve xxx:xxx-retrofit2:1.2.2-20190605.095405-1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Can you run it with the --debug command that usually helps to find out the exact issue

Comment: I think I found something useful from the debug, thanks @SaranSankaran

Comment: Post an appropriate solution for your issue closed the question dude :)